# Patient Who did not have visit in 2015 and Their Last Visit date

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Below is the Script to pull the patients that did not see the provider from 2014/7/1 till today. Now I will like to have a new column where I can have when was their last encounter date How do I do that?  Below is shown the tables with columns.

*Please let me know if you have any questions.*

```
SELECT p.first_name, p.last_name, p.date_of_birth, 
       p1.age, p.home_phone, p.cell_phone, 
       p.primarycareprovname, pe.enctimestamp, 
       pe.encnbr, p.city, p.zip, p.person_id    
FROM person AS p 
Inner join patient_ P1 
        on p.person_id=p1.person_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Patient_encounter PE 
        ON pe.person_id =p.person_id 
       AND pe.enctimestamp BETWEEN '20140701' AND '20160131'

WHERE pe.person_id IS NULL 
  and p1.age>'59' 
  and p.city like '%Paris%'
```

[image: Click on this Link to see the table with columns]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `GROUP BY` and `MAX()`:

```
SELECT p.first_name, p.last_name, p.date_of_birth, p1.age, p.home_phone, 
       p.cell_phone, p.primarycareprovname,
       MAX(pe.enctimestamp) as most_recent_date, p.city, p.zip, p.person_id
FROM person AS p Inner join
     patient_ P1
     on p.person_id = p1.person_id LEFT OUTER JOIN
     Patient_encounter PE
      ON pe.person_id = p.person_id AND
         pe.enctimestamp BETWEEN '20140701' AND '20160131'
WHERE pe.person_id IS NULL and p1.age  >'59' and p.city like '%Paris%'
GROUP BY p.person_id;
```

Comment: it displays the null value on the most_recent_data even tho patient has data on the table

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT x.first_name, x.person_id, MAX(pe2.enctimestamp) as LastEncounterDate
FROM

(SELECT p.first_name, p.last_name, p.date_of_birth, 
       p1.age, p.home_phone, p.cell_phone, 
       p.primarycareprovname, pe.enctimestamp, 
       pe.encnbr, p.city, p.zip, p.person_id    
FROM person AS p 
Inner join patient_ P1 
        on p.person_id=p1.person_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Patient_encounter PE 
        ON pe.person_id =p.person_id 
       AND pe.enctimestamp BETWEEN '20140701' AND '20160131'
WHERE pe.person_id IS NULL 
  and p1.age>'59' 
  and p.city like '%Paris%') x

INNER JOIN Patient_encounter PE2 
    ON pe2.person_id =x.person_id
WHERE pe2.enctimestamp < '20140701'
GROUP BY x.first_name, x.person_id
```